# Can prayer change God's mind?

Tags: nature-of-god, prayer, providence

Since the Bible states that God has a plan for us, and he is in charge of our lives, then if he wants your family member or friend to die of cancer, and you don't, and you are praying for him to get rid of the cancer, will you change God's mind?